# How to insert a tag in a string to replace a letter and to customize it?

Tags: html, reactjs, tags, components

I want to insert an html tag in order to customize a single letter. The problem is that the result is [object object].
What's the error?

```
const getAndChangeCustomI = (content) => {
    let iIndex = content.indexOf("i");
    let insert = [];
    insert.push(<span className="customLetterI" > I</span>)
    content.slice(0, iIndex) + content.slice(iIndex + 1);
    if (iIndex > 0) {
        return content.substring(0, iIndex) + insert[0] + content.substr(iIndex);
    }
    return insert + content;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to concatenate a string with an array of nodes. You should construct the return value to be nodes in order to preserve the span:

```
return <>{content.substring(0, iIndex)}{insert[0]}{content.substr(iIndex)}</>;
```

Comment: Hi, it doesn't work either. I got just [object object] without anything from the string.

Comment: Are you sure nothing else is impacting it? I can run your code with my above suggestion and it works fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-saha-7tmch

Comment: Hi, your code works perfectly, the problem was "dangerouslySetInnerHTML" in the content tag. Thanks a lot.